# Webpack HMR reloading entire app in some routes

Tags: react-router, webpack-hmr, react-hot-loader

First of all, I'm using:

- "react-router": "3.0.2",
- browser-sync": "2.18.8",
- "url-loader": "0.5.7",
- "webpack": "1.13.1",
- "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.6.1",
- "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.12.2",
- "material-ui": "0.17.0",

Ok, now Webpack HMR is working only when I edit reactjs components that are part of the main route, I mean: `myurlapp.com/`

But if a component is part from another route, example: `myurlapp.com/form` then the entire app is reloaded. Why is that?

My root js is this:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
    import routes from './routes';
    import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
    require('./favicon.ico');
    import './styles.scss';
    import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
    import 'flexboxgrid/css/flexboxgrid.css';

    injectTapEventPlugin();

    render(
        <Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory} />, document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

routes.js is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './containers/App';
import NotFoundPage from './containers/NotFoundPage.js';
import LoginPage from './containers/LoginPage';
import FormPage from './containers/FormPage';
import TablePage from './containers/TablePage';
import Dashboard from './containers/DashboardPage';

export default (
  <Route>
    <Route path="login" component={LoginPage}/>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
      <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
      <Route path="form" component={FormPage}/>
      <Route path="table" component={TablePage}/>
      <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
);
```

And by the way, this is the entries of webpack:

```
entry: [
  './src/webpack-public-path',
  'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
  './src/index'
],
```

What other code should I show? This is what I see in the console of Chrome Dev Tools:
[image: HMR in Dev Tools]
as you can see, I edited the code of Header.js and the update was made ok (without reloading the entire app) but if I edit another component, someone who is exclusive for a router different than the main /  then the entire app is realoaded.